# Show Custom Taxonomy Categories, Listing of Posts, and Single Post via AJAX

Tags: posts, categories, taxonomy, ajax, listing

I need to be able to do the following:

- List all terms in a custom taxonomy (categories for custom post type)
- When a user clicks on a category, a listing of all posts in that category appears
- When a user clicks on a post, that individual post content appears

This needs to be done via AJAX in order for all of this to happen on one page, I just don't know how to do it. I've searched here and other site but haven't found a solution so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!