# How to order posts by taxonomy in WP_Query

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, wp-query

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using wp_query is it possible to orderby taxonomy?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14306/using-wp-query-is-it-possible-to-orderby-taxonomy)

I have a page template that should show CPTs grouped by taxonomy.
I'd like to get all the CPTs in a single query and not query by taxonomy (i.e. create a different query for each term)

Is there a proper way to do that ?

Comment: Please show us your [research efforts](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=order%20by%20taxonomy).

Comment: yep, did the search. I want a *single* query (for performance) didn't find anything like it. this : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/64663/show-custom-taxonomy-categories-listing-of-posts-and-single-post-via-ajax is similar, but with no answer...

Comment: Take a look at Otto's answer to this question http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14306/using-wp-query-is-it-possible-to-orderby-taxonomy